# Fill excel with data frame data if their data matches

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, openpyxl

So, i have to fill an excel sheet (i'm using openpyxl to obtain the data from the sheet) using data from a dataframe, the excel and the dataframe have an account column and if they match other cell need to be filled with the data from the DF.

i tried  looping through the  sheet to obtain the cell value and validate it, but i don't get how to fill the other cells

```py
  for  row in df_App.iterrows(): 
       for cell in target['C']:
              if  cell.value == row[1]["Cuenta"]:
                print(cell.value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fill a cell with openpyxl:

```py
sheet.cell(row=RowNum, col=ColNum).value = YourValue
```